# How to make a HDF-3.4.1.1-centos7-rpm.tar.gz file?

Tags: hdf

I have a HDP 3.1.4 cluster with local repository. I want to install HDF mpack but it needs the file HDF-3.4.1.1-centos7-rpm.tar.gz. You know, from now on, without valid account, you cannot download the file from Cloudera at https://archive.cloudera.com/p/HDF/3.x/3.4.1.1/centos7/HDF-3.4.1.1-centos7-rpm.tar.gz.

I want to setup a HDF local repository. Can someone please guide me how to make the HDF-3.4.1.1-centos7-rpm.tar.gz? Note that it should be compatible with Ambari 2.7.4.0.

Thanks,
Giang.